# Fixed DIVs inside a scrollable DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make top two divs in a scrollable fixed on top of the scrollable DIV and, and in each scrollable DIV I would like to make first two child divs fixed like top elements. Please see my HTML and CSS here http://jsfiddle.net/wDmMB/2/

```
 var div = $('<div />');
 $('.p-r:lt(3)').each(function(){
     div.append($(this));
 }); 
 div.css({
     position:'absolute',
     top:0,
     left:0
 });
 $('.topP').append(div);
 $('.topP').scroll(function(){
   div.css({
     top : $(this).scrollTop() + "px",
     left : $(this).scrollLeft() + "px"
   });
 });
```

But this is not working. How can I achieve that. Please help me on this.

**Update:**
To make more clear, I would like to implement freezed panes functionality as in tables.

Comment: Can you please make what you are trying to achieve more clear. At the moment, it doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Are you after something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/kJ9xp/

Comment: @gvee Absolutely.. In the struggle for sticky columns also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not clear about your problem but i have set a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/wDmMB/4/)

```
which i understand according to your problem
```

Comment: Exactly, Could you please help me to implement left size two columns freezing as rows are freezed at top now

Comment: from left side it is fixed alreday dear can you explain more i am not understanding your problem